# how to make apache case-sensitive when parse html resources

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache

```
<html><script src="js/Test.js"></script></html>
```

I find the apache will load test.js or tEst.js.it doesn't care the case-sensitive. so how to make the apache case-sensitive about javascript files and css files.I don't know which part of my apache is wrong.so how to fix that!
thks

Comment: I cannot use this as answer, but a found this : http://blog.servergrove.com/2010/08/24/fixing-problems-with-case-sensitive-urls/ ...

Comment: check on apache mode_speling module. (CheckSpelling on|off) http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html

Answer (score 1):

On windows machines the filesystem is not case sensitive. I belive you can also install OSX without case sensitive file names (which is generally a bad idea). On Linux machines the above would not work since file system it is case sensitive.

Edit: According to the apache manual this configuration should probably also work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lowercase:$1} [R,L]
```

It requires that you enable mod-rewrite in your apache conf.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/platform/windows.html

Comment: OS X uses a case-insensitive filesystem by default. Using a case-sensitive file system is a bad idea as it will break some software that depends on case sensitivity.